# How do I open this application using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to debug the following code :

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String

    strArgument = ""

    'Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus)
    Call Shell(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\eclipse.exe ", vbReadOnly)

End Sub
```

This code runs when I click on a particular button in excel
However, when I run the code/ click the button, I get the following error:

> Run time error 5
>   Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: I think the `vbReadOnly` is for workbooks, not an executable.

Comment: this code  actually ran an executable, for some reason, it has a bug now; maybe the file path has changed?

Comment: Well, you tell us if the file exists at the location your code is expecting it... which seems rather unlikely, unless you have a habit of saving Excel workbooks in the install folder of an IDE. FWIW `Call` is redundant, `Shell "command"` is all you need